# How do I configure an SVN repository using Eclipse Juno Subversive?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-juno, subversive

I'm using Eclipse Juno and trying to configure version control for my projects.  I installed Subversive and am trying to configure my SVN repository, but when I go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> SVN, there is no "Repository" tab, as the documentation suggests -- [Eclipse Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_svn.php).  There is only "General", "SVN Connector," "Project Structure," "View Settings," and "Error Reporting."

Consequently, when I right click on my project and select "Team", there is no "Commit" option -- I assume because I don't have a repository configured.  How do I configure a repository in Subversive?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-enable-subversion-svn-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 2):

Open the SVN Repositories view ie Window -> Show View... -> Other.  Hunt for the SVN folder and you will see the SVN Repositories view.  Once it is open, right click in the view and follow the New option.  I'm sure at that point it's self-explanatory.

I see that I have a repository configured, but I don't think I ever actually use it.

Here's how I work with SVN-hosted projects.  If it's a brand new project, I simply create the project, copy it to my SVN sandbox, check it in to SVN, then copy the SVN managed project back to my workspace - or do SVN->Check Out... from Tortoise on my desktop.

Once the project is under SVN a refresh will show all the SVN information in the Project Explorer.

The project has to already be under SVN before you can see the Team->Commit Team->Update stuff.  I prefer to check my projects in manually from the desktop folder. But once they are checked in, I manage them 100% in eclipse.

Comment: My projects were in my workspace and I was able to interact with SVN successfully using the command line.  I followed your instructions and added the repository location, however, when I right click on any workspace project and go to "Team", the only options are "Apply Patch," "Share Project," and "Share Projects."  Any ideas how to get the "Team" -> "Commit" option to appear?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't recognize that these are in SVN, bu I'm not sure why not. :-(

Comment: One last comment (answer?) - right click on the project. Select Team -> Share Project....   Walk through the wizard to add this project to SVN.  I just tried this because I wanted to see what Share Project... would do. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Team > Share Project  worked for me too ! After that right click on the project you want to commit. Go To Team > Commit. It will then show the list of files that have been changed. Un-check the ones you don't want to commit. Let the others remain checked & click on finish.